# get_status() function returns 1 instead of true or false, why?

Tags: php, oop, class

In the code below the get_status() method in my website class returns 1 instead of true or false like I want it to. Can anyone tell me why please? I think it's probably a mistake in my class, I'm not sure if this line of code is good practice within the get_status() method?

$httpcode = $this->get_httpcode();

When I echo $siteUp it is always 1 whether I put the url as http://www.google.com or http://www.dsfdsfsdsdfsdfsdf.com

I am fairly new to object orientated php and this is my first time teaching myself classes and this is an example I'm building to learn oop. It's desigened to check a website status and say whether it's up or down based on the httpcode.

Any tips you have in why this isn't working would be greatly recieved. Thanks in advance!

```
class website {
protected $url;

function __construct($url) {
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function get_url() {
    return $this->url;
}

public function get_httpcode() {
    //get the http status code
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    $page=curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $httpcode;
}

public function get_status() {
    $httpcode = $this->get_httpcode();
    if ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<400) {
         $siteUp = true;
    } else {
        $siteUp = false;
    }
    return $siteUp;
}
}

// create an instance of the website class and pass the url
$website = new website("http://www.google.com");
$url = $website->get_url();
$httpcode = $website->get_httpcode();
$siteUp = $website->get_status();
echo "site up is set to: " . $siteUp;
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing the `$httpcode` first?

Comment: Why not just `return $httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<400;`?

Comment: Other than the http code, it would be wise to check the value of `curl_exec` as well (in your case, variable `$page`). The value of `$page` would be false on failure,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 is just how PHP converts "true" to a string

```
<?php echo true; ?>
```

Will display 1.

In PHP, testing against 1 and testing against true are mostly the same thing.

```
$siteUp = $website->get_status() ? "true" : "false";
```

will make it a string for you to display... but you then can't test against it for truth, since both "true" and "false" are valid strings and will give you a boolean TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a boolean, which is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (but not the *words* true or false).

You can either return a string instead or convert it before you append it to the echo statement:

For example:

```
public function get_status() {
    $httpcode = $this->get_httpcode();
    if ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<400) {
     $siteUp = 'true';
    } else {
    $siteUp = 'false';
    }
    return $siteUp;
}
```

Or if you want to keep it as a Boolean being returned, you can use a really simple function to convert it to a string like this:

```
public function showBool($myBool)
{
    return ($myBool) ? 'True' : 'False';
}

$someVar=false;
echo showBool($someVar);
```

Answer (score 2):

As a simple exercise, try running the below code and see for yourself:

```
<?php 
    echo true;
?>
```

What you are trying to do is print a boolean value, and expect a string "true" or "false". You could do something like:

```
$booleanVal? "true":"false";
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid printing out `true`/`false`. Use an if-statement to see what it actually returns. 
What are you expecting `$siteUp` to print?

```
if($siteUp) { 
    echo "Up"; 
} else { 
    echo "Down"; 
}
```