# php returns 1 on browser

Tags: php, methods, return

I got a simple Question. I use the expression `<?=a_function();?>` very often in my system but each and every time it shows "1" on my page when a_function() returns true. What else can I do? I heard I should always return something but whats this with this 1?

Comment: <?= is perfectly valid shorthand for echoing.

Comment: Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139200/get-status-function-returns-1-instead-of-true-or-false-why) - "1" is how php converts true to string.

Answer (score 4):

`1` or `0` is a boolean, which is equivalent to `true` or `false`.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

[How does true/false work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php)

Also, if you just want to run the function without outputting anything, just use `<?php a_function(); ?>`

Comment: what if i want to use <?=?> without getting 1 in return? shall i create a function withour return true?

Comment: No. `<?= a_function(); ?>` is the direct equivalent of writing `<?php echo a_function(); ?>`. The `<?=` is supposed to be a shorthand alternative for echoing whatever was returned. Use `<?php` instead and you'll run the function -- all without echoing what was returned.

Comment: and would you say its mandatory to declare a result?

Comment: It's good practice to return either a value, `true`, or `false`/`null` from a function. If you're not returning anything, returning `true` or a value designates that the function was successful; returning `false` or `null` designates that something within the function did not properly validate.

Comment: and `return;` is bad practice?

Comment: Long story short, if the function is successful, you want to return either the value you're returning or `true`. If the function is not successful, returning `false` is best practice. PHP is a loosely typed language, so it's good to be able to consistently use the `===` operator to check for a return of `false`. This will help avoid issues where a return of `null` or `0` could issue a false-positive during validation checks using the `==` operator. I suggest this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643080/what-is-the-php-best-practice-for-using-functions-that-return-true-or-false

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of what you're doing?
I have'nt understand it,but I think the `a_function();` returns the integer value of a boolean expression.
a boolean expression is always `1` or `0` that `1=true` and `0=false`.
For Example,in PHP if you type `1==0;`,It will return false and if you echo it as an integer,it'll print `0`.
also,you are using `=` in you're code.delete it and you're page will show nothing.

Comment: for instance `a_function($message);` loads a message from the database and "echos" it. if i return true it'll show the message and a 1..